# How to insert a string after a specific section of another string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm working with a specific API that returns a class as a string to me. I need to insert a string at a certain block of the string that is given to me. So basically a function that takes the whole string, and appends the string I want to add to it after a specific block.

The string passed to me is a java class, and I want to basically enter my own function at the end of it after all of the existing functions. Incase you are confused.. I don't have access to the java file, this is the only way to modify the file when you are using config plugins in expo react native.

I believe some sort of regex is supposed to be used to get this  result ? but really I have no idea how to target the specific part of the string.

**The string I want to add:**

'@Override\nprotected List getPackages() {\nreturn Arrays.asList(\nnew MainReactPackage(), // <---- add comma\nnew RNFSPackage() // <---------- add package\n);\n}'

**The string that is passed to me**

```
import expo.modules.updates.UpdatesDevLauncherController;
import expo.modules.devlauncher.DevLauncherController;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;

import expo.modules.ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher;
import expo.modules.ReactNativeHostWrapper;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.JSIModulePackage;
import com.swmansion.reanimated.ReanimatedJSIModulePackage;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {
  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHostWrapper(
    this,
    new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return DevLauncherController.getInstance().getUseDeveloperSupport();
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
      List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
      // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
      // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
      return packages;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
      return "index";
    }

    @Override
    protected JSIModulePackage getJSIModulePackage() {
      return new ReanimatedJSIModulePackage();
    }
  });

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);

    DevLauncherController.initialize(this, getReactNativeHost());
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
      DevLauncherController.getInstance().setUpdatesInterface(UpdatesDevLauncherController.initialize(this));
    }
    initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
    ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.onApplicationCreate(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onConfigurationChanged(@NonNull Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.onConfigurationChanged(this, newConfig);
  }

<--- I WANT TO INSERT MY STRING HERE

  /**
   * Loads Flipper in React Native templates. Call this in the onCreate method with something like
   * initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
   *
   * @param context
   * @param reactInstanceManager
   */
  private static void initializeFlipper(
      Context context, ReactInstanceManager reactInstanceManager) {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
      try {
        /*
         We use reflection here to pick up the class that initializes Flipper,
        since Flipper library is not available in release mode
        */
        Class<?> aClass = Class.forName("com.haibert.GitTest.ReactNativeFlipper");
        aClass
            .getMethod("initializeFlipper", Context.class, ReactInstanceManager.class)
            .invoke(null, context, reactInstanceManager);
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `(?<=})[\s]*?(?=}\s*$)`?  https://regex101.com/r/xLhOCw/1

Comment: @Daniel I apologize, I didnt paste the entire string because I did not know how regex works, Your regex was correct but not working because I had not copy pasted the entire string. I have updated the string now, can you please provide the regex for the section with the new updated string ?

Comment: Okay, updated.  Will that block of code always be the same?  The regex is looking specifically for that "/**\n   * Loads Flipper" part. https://regex101.com/r/xLhOCw/2

Comment: @Daniel yes for now it will, later there will be a better solution provided by expo and we wont have to use regex. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
const addToMainApp = (content) => {
    const regexpPackagingOptions = /\s*?(?=\/\*\*\n   \* Loads Flipper)/
    const insertLocation = content.match(regexpPackagingOptions)

    const newContent =
        content.substring(0, insertLocation.index) +
        '//INSERTED \n@Override\nprotected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {\nreturn Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(\nnew MainReactPackage(), // <---- add comma\nnew RNFSPackage() // <---------- add package\n);\n}' +
        content.substring(insertLocation.index, content.length)

    return newContent
}
```